# Grunt configuration of dynamic dev or prod API domain token replace?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

We are using grunt.js for our build utility and we were asked to have it distinguish a production version and a development version.

The requirement is that we have a large API to connect to between the two and they need two separate domains. For example, dev.com or prod.com.

How would you use grunt to token replace different domains (in the source) between dev or prod?

In other words, how can grunt conditionally configure a dynamic domain name and replace it in the source code, as a result of the dev/prod build process?

Update: it looks like grunt-string-replace or grunt-replace may be the answer...

any input on this?

Comment: Where do you store the flag now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-string-replace

- grunt-string-replace is looking good.

Going to give it a try...

HERE WAS THE Token Replace PART OF THE ANSWER:

```
//STRING-REPLACE-.
//Domain-Tokens for different builds. Multiple file, multiple replacement.
,
'string-replace': {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'dest/': 'tokenreplace.js'
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [
      {
        pattern: 'Domain-Token',
        replacement: 'hello from domain token.'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grunt runs in node, and when you run node in prod, you set `NODE_ENV=production grunt` (in the command prompt).  You should be able to access the variable from within your grunt file via `process.env.NODE_ENV`.  You can name your environments whatever you like, but **production** and **development** are pretty standard (I also use **local** for developing on my local machine).

You can also pass in your own custom parameters instead: `grunt --param=value` and from within your grunt file you access it via `grunt.option("param"); // => "value"`